# Question about smart pointers in C++

Tags: c++

Is auto_ptr good to work with only for local variables?
If I need to work with classes too, do i need copied pointer ?

Comment: I really don't know what's being asked here....

Comment: What would be the purpose of auto_ptr for local variables? Why would you need any different behavior for classes? Your question leaves more questions.

Comment: well,if i use auto_ptr for a function variable,when i exit the function doesnt the destructor being called ?

Comment: @vBx, yes, that's the entire purpose of smart pointers in general (which is part of what makes your question confusing). Note, however, that in recent compilers, `std::auto_ptr` has been deprecated in favor of `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: From your comment, maybe you need to review the concept of scopes. I believe if you understood scoping better you would have the answer to your question.

Comment: i kind of figure out after the first 2 post that my question is confusing, but that is because i just study about them,and i read that auto_ptr should only be choosed when working with local variables,  copied pointers with class members, big objects with COW. So in short can i use auto_ptr to be a class member ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto_ptr destructor does deallocate the memory, so you are correct.  Once you leave the auto_ptr's scope the thing you're pointing to will go away.  You might be looking for something like a shared_ptr, which is a reference counted smart pointer.  It will be part of the next C++ standard.  [Boost has an implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) of it, and it's also [part of the TR1 library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_tr1/subject_list.html#boost_tr1.subject_list.ptrs).  If your compiler supports std::tr1 entities then you should have the shared_ptr.

**Edit**

As pointed out in comments, auto_ptr copy semantics cause a transfer of ownership that does not necessarily result in deletion of the object.  So, an auto_ptr type variable can be assigned to another, and could be used as a function return value.  The key with auto_ptr is that only one of them at a time can reference a particular entity.

I think I was assigning the traits of [scoped_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) to auto_ptr incorrectly and a little unfairly. My own bias is against auto_ptr because that transfer of ownership causes a side effect on the source object that is not normally associated with copying.

Comment: Note that `boost::scoped_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` are the apples-to-apples proper replacements for `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: actually `std::auto_ptr`'s copy constructor implements ownership transfer semantic, so if you return a local `auto_ptr` the ownership will be transferred to the returned instance of `auto_ptr` i.e. to the caller.

Comment: @matteo: I stand corrected.  Thank you.  Will edit to reflect that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't *required* to use pointers in C++ in many cases, so you may not need any kind of smart pointer:

```
struct Foo {
    int bar;
    int twice_bar()
    {
        return 2 * bar;
    }
};

int twice_x(int x)
{
    Foo f;
    f.bar = x;
    return f.twice_bar();
}
```